# How to parse SVN output in Node.js using RegexP?

Tags: regex, node.js, svn

I want to parse the subversion log outputs get filtered information and store them in a DB table. Unfortunately there is no svn wrapper for Node.js. I have revision number column for revision id's, file column to store the all data and another id which is written in message. Since I am so new in regex, I tried to parse it from xml-we could get svn output in xml format(--xml)- so far I gave a try for writing a regex pattern, but not any luck. Here is what I have:

```
var fs = require ('fs');

var fileName = "svnout.txt";

exports.svnparse = function(req, res) {

    fs.readFile(fileName, {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function (err, data) {

        if(err) { throw err;
        } else {
            console.log(data.toString());
            return res.send(parseSvn(data));
        }
    });
};
var parseSvn = function(data) {
      var logs = data.split('------------------------------------------------------------------------');

      var data = [];
      logs = logs.slice(1, -1);
      for (var log in logs) {
      var pattern = '\r\nr(?P<rev>\d+)\s+\|\s+(?P<author>\w+)\s+\|\s+(?P<timestamp>.*?)\s||\s+(?P<messages>.*?)\s|';

var match = logs[log].match(pattern);;
        data.push({rid: match[1], name: match[2], date: match[3], message: match[4]});
            saveToDB(data);
      }
      return {logs: data};
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [node-svn-spawn](https://github.com/ddliu/node-svn-spawn), the `getLog` result example:

```
[
    {
      "$": {
        "revision": "1"
      },
      "author": "dong",
      "date": "2013-11-08T02:10:37.656902Z",
      "msg": "init repo"
    },
    ...
]
```

There are many other SVN commands supported, such as add, status, commit, info, etc.

If you want to parse it your own, try [node-xml2js](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out it this way for future references:

```
var command = 'svn log '+ someSvnServerUrl + " -r {" + date + "}:{" + todate + "}" ;
var command = 'svn log --xml '+ someSvnServerUrl  + " -r {" + date + "}:{" + todate + "}";
return exec(command, function(err, stdout) {
     if (err) {
         console.log("Error on svn get", err);
         return cb(err);
     } else {
        return cb(null, parseSvn(stdout));
    }
```